# Linkedin Javascript SDK : [unauthorized]. IP Address Mismatch

Tags: javascript, sdk, linkedin-api

We have used Javascript SDK of Linked In : developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk

Our purpose is to fetch the linked in public profile photo and display it in our website. We have already implemented the javascript API code in our website which is mentioned below.

**Problem** : 
1) Photos are fetched and shown in some machines but in 1 or 2 machines there is a response like "[unauthorized]. IP Address Mismatch". Please see the attached screen shot. [IP Address Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od60i.png) All machines are located at different places.

2) We have used same website URL : marketplace.siriusdecisions.com/Vendor/Acquia

Here you can see linked in profile photos are in section "Corporate executives
edit". You can go to particular pubic profile URL by clicking on that image.
But some machine we can not see the images.

3) We have used the public profile url like :
linkedin.com/in/rajesh-kasundra-a068305

linkedin.com/in/ashish-mistry-023ab264

4) All the machines have the permission of linked in and also can access these two public profile URL. we can see the profile photo in this URL from all machines

5) So what should be the problem? Is it regarding some machine configuration problem?

6) We have also mentioned our code snipped at.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkedIn_api_key"]
    // We have used API key from Web.Config
    authorize: false
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

 function onLinkedInLoad() {      
        $.each(LinkedInAccounts, function (index, item) {          
            getDetails(item.url);
            executiveid = LinkedInAccounts[index].id;
        });      
        tid = setInterval(LoadLinkedInImages, 1000);    
    }
    function LoadLinkedInImages() {
        if (LinkedInAccounts.length == executiveSrc.length) {
            $.each(executiveSrc, function (index, item) {                
                var u = item.values[0]._key.split("=")[1];
                if (item.values[0].pictureUrls.values) {
                    $(".executiveImage[data-executiveurl='" + u + "']").attr('src', item.values[0].pictureUrls.values);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".executiveImage[data-executiveurl='" + u + "']").attr('src', "/Content/Images/notfound.jpg");
                }
            });
            abortTimer();
        }
    }
    function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
        clearInterval(tid);
    }
    function displayProfiles(data) {      
        executiveSrc.push(data);
    }
    function displayProfilesErrors(error) {
        
    }
    function getDetails(url) {
        IN.API.Profile(url)
            .fields("firstName", "picture-urls::(original)", "picture-url")
          .result(displayProfiles)
          .error(displayProfilesErrors);
    }
```

Thanks,
Bhavik Kabaria